# .NET Core Gateway Socket Exception

Tags: .net-core, wso2

I have a .NET Core service which is published to WSO2 API Gateway, this service talks to another service hosted in the WSO2 API Gateway too.

This service runs in a Linux Container on OpenShift.

One of the API is failing for few requests with Socket Exception

> System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCanceledException: The operation was canceled.
>
> System.IO.IOException: Unable to read data from the transport connection: The I/O operation has been aborted because of either a thread exit or an application request..
>
> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (995): The I/O operation has been aborted because of either a thread exit or an application request.
> --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
> at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.AwaitableSocketAsyncEventArgs.ThrowException(SocketError error, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
> at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.AwaitableSocketAsyncEventArgs.GetResult(Int16 token)
> at System.Net.Http.HttpConnection.FillAsync()
> at System.Net.Http.HttpConnection.ReadNextResponseHeaderLineAsync(Boolean foldedHeadersAllowed)
> at System.Net.Http.HttpConnection.SendAsyncCore(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
> --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
> at System.Net.Http.HttpConnection.SendAsyncCore(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
> at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.SendWithNtConnectionAuthAsync(HttpConnection connection, HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean doRequestAuth, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
> at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.SendWithRetryAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean doRequestAuth, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
> at System.Net.Http.RedirectHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
> at System.Net.Http.DiagnosticsHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
> at System.Net.Http.HttpClient.FinishSendAsyncBuffered(Task`1 sendTask, HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationTokenSource cts, Boolean disposeCts) at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ActionMethodExecutor.TaskOfIActionResultExecutor.Execute(IActionResultTypeMapper mapper, ObjectMethodExecutor executor, Object controller, Object[] arguments) at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeActionMethodAsync>g__Awaited|12_0(ControllerActionInvoker invoker, ValueTask`1 actionResultValueTask)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.g__Awaited|10_0(ControllerActionInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Rethrow(ActionExecutedContextSealed context)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.g__Awaited|13_0(ControllerActionInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.g__Awaited|19_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.g__Logged|17_1(ResourceInvoker invoker)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware.g__AwaitRequestTask|6_0(Endpoint endpoint, Task requestTask, ILogger logger)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AuthorizationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
> at Serilog.AspNetCore.RequestLoggingMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
> at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerUI.SwaggerUIMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
> at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Swagger.SwaggerMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext, ISwaggerProvider swaggerProvider)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.Extensions.UsePathBaseMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)

This is my code

```
public static async Task<DataDTO> JsonPostAsync(DataDTO datDTO, string access_token, string adfsToken)
{
    DataDTO APIResult = new DataDTO();

    using (HttpClientHandler handler = new HttpClientHandler())
    {
        using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient(handler))
        {
            try
            {
                var fooFullUrl = "https://urloftheotherservice";
                HttpResponseMessage response = null;
                            
                // tried clearing out the headers
                client.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5);   
                // specifying timeout also does not help
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + access_token);
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("x-mt-adfs-openid", adfsToken);
                
                var fooJSON = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(DataDTO, new JsonSerializerSettings
                        {
                            ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver()
                        });

                using (var fooContent = new StringContent(fooJSON, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json"))
                {
                    response = await client.PostAsync(fooFullUrl, fooContent);
                    // Error occurs here
                }
            }
            catch (HttpRequestException ex)
            {
                APIResult.ReturnMessage = ex.Message.ToString();
            }
        }
    }

    return APIResult;
}
```

The data size is 1MB.

Comment: Do you see any errors in WSO2 gateway?